# I have an array of objects, and I want to emit a signal containing a single one of these objects. But the signal can't be a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, class, assignment-operator

I'm working on a GUI which will control different robotic arms. One of the required functions of the GUI is that it must be able to send trajectory commands, where a trajectory contains a variable number of destinations (called 'setpoints'). Each setpoint is a series of joint angles, one angle per degree of freedom of the robot.

I've defined the following class to contain individual trajectories:

```
class trajectory{
public:
    QString trajName;
    int DOF;
    int count;

    double** fullTraj;

    QString getTrajString(trajectory);

    trajectory(const QString&, const int&, const int&);
    trajectory operator = (const trajectory);
    ~trajectory();
};
```

where trajName is the name of the trajectory, count is the number of setpoints for this trajectory, DOF is degrees of freedom, and fullTraj is going to be a 2d array with dimensions count x DOF. Here are the constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor:

```
trajectory::trajectory (const QString& name, const int& trajcount, const int& trajDOF){
    trajName = name;
    count = trajcount;
    DOF = trajDOF;
    fullTraj = new double*[count];
}

trajectory::trajectory(const trajectory &traj){
    trajName = traj.trajName;
    count = traj.count;
    DOF = traj.DOF;
    fullTraj = new double*[count];
    for (int row = 0; row < count; row++){
        for (int column = 0; column<DOF; column++){
            fullTraj[row][column] = traj.fullTraj[row][column];
        }
    }
}
trajectory trajectory:: operator = ( const trajectory oldtraj){
    trajectory newTraj;
    newTraj.count = oldtraj.count;
    newTraj.DOF = oldtraj.DOF;
    newTraj.trajName = oldtraj.trajName;

    newTraj.fullTraj = new double*[newTraj.count];

    return newTraj;
}

trajectory::~trajectory(){
    delete fullTraj;
}


QString trajectory::getTrajString(trajectory* traj){
    QString trajString = "' " + traj->trajName + " '\n";
    for (int row = 0; row <traj->count; row++){
        trajString += "\t [ ";
        for (int column = 0; column < traj->DOF; column++){
            trajString += "  " + QString::number(traj->fullTraj[row][column],'f',2 );
        }
        trajString += " ] \n";
    }
    return trajString;
}
```

I want to create an array of trajectories, and I've attempted to do this like so:

In my header file:

```
trajectory* trajectories;
```

And in the cpp:

```
 for (int i = 0; i<numberOfTrajs; i++){
     trajectories[i] =  new trajectory("Empty Trajectory", 0,0);
 }
```

When the user wants to send the robot to a particular signal, he clicks a button. When the button is clicked, I want to emit a signal with the specific trajectory that the user wants to send. I could do this like so:

```
emit sigSendTrajCommand(trajectories[i])
```

where i indicates which trajectory is to be sent. But emitting a signal as a pointer seems wrong. I tried to send it as a pointer anyway, but the trajectory received by the slot is filled with trash, even though the one emitted is not (I verfied this using qDebug, I can print values from the trajectory immediately before emitting the signal, but the application crashes with I attempt to print values in the slot).

Here is the slot that emits the signal with a specific trajectory, which I will later add to the array of trajectories:

```
void robotTrajWidget::on_sendTraj_clicked()
{
   ui->trajDisplay->moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start);
   ui->trajDisplay->insertPlainText(QTime::currentTime().toString() + "\tMoving robot to '" + thistrajName + "':\n");

   getTrajectory();
   emit sigSendTrajectory(myTraj);
   delete myTraj->fullTraj;
}
```

Where getTrajectory(); reads in values from a QTableWidget:

```
void robotTrajWidget::getTrajectory(){
        myTraj = new trajectory(thistrajName, trajCount, newDOF);
        for (int i = 0; i<trajCount; i++){
            myTraj->fullTraj[i] = new double[newDOF];
        }
        for (int row = 0; row<trajCount; row++){
            for (int column = 0; column<newDOF; column++){
                myTraj->fullTraj[row][column] = trajTable->item(row,column)->text().toDouble();
            }
        }

    }
```

When the slot receives the trajectory, I want to be able to simply add the new trajectory to the array of trajectories. I've attempted to do so:

```
void robotTabWidget::slotOnNewTrajButton(trajectory newTraj){


    trajectories[trajCount] = newTraj;

    setButtons[trajCount]->setText(newTraj.trajName);
    setButtons[trajCount]->setObjectName(newTraj.trajName);

    connect(setButtons[trajCount],SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(onSetButtonsClicked(bool)));
    ui->jointsetPointLayout->addWidget(setButtons[trajCount],buttonRow,buttonColumn);

    if (buttonColumn == 3){
        buttonRow +=1;
        buttonColumn = 0;
    }

    else buttonColumn +=1;
    trajCount+=1;
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
error: cannot convert 'trajectory' to 'trajectory*' in assignment
 trajectories[trajCount] = newTraj;
                         ^
```

I want to store the trajectories in the array, and then be able to emit individual trajectories as a signal when the user wants to do so. Basically, I want to send them as non-pointers, store them in an array of pointers, and then send them again as non-pointers. How can I do that?

Edit: Let me clarify a little more. Initially, the user loads a trajectory from a text file. I want the user to be able to store multiple trajectories, so I have an array of trajectories, and each loaded trajectory is added to this array of trajectories. Then, when the user wants to send the robot to a trajectory, I want to pick out the trajectory from the array and emit that array as a signal. This signal will go to a slot which does not have access to the entire array of trajectories, so sending the index of the trajectory won't work.

Comment: I admit I didn't read that wall of text and code, but why bother storing pointers in the first place? If copying is cheap enough (or if you make it a shared class), why not just store a `QList` of them?

Comment: QList is an array of pointers anyway, isn't it? What's the advantage of QList over a normal array?

Comment: The advantage of `QList` is that it behaves like a list of values, even though internally it is represented as a list of pointers.

Comment: I also didn't read the whole wall of text but I was looking through the code and you mentioned seeing garbage when passing pointers, and I could not see where you actually initialize `trajectory* trajectories;` - I see your for loop indexing it, but do you actually do `trajectories = new trajectory*[numberOfTrajs];` first? If you don't then when you do `trajectories[i] = new...`, you're assigning the address of that new object to some garbage location.

Comment: Uhm - you only allocate one dimension of `fullTraj` in every case, and you've misunderstood `operator=`.

Comment: After reading it a little bit, I got even more confused: if you get trash from a sent pointer (and sending pointers via signals is a perfectly fine thing to do as long as you're sure the pointer stays valid in the mean time), then you'd better solve *that* first. You obviously have a memory corruption problem. I suggest you run it under Valgrind if you have access to a Linux system.

Comment: After reading a bit more, I realized that your code just have too many issues. You obviously don't know how copying, memory allocation, arrays and and assignments work in C++ (your assignment operator is a real mess, for example). I suggest you brush up your C++ skills before attempting to do anything this serious. Read Stroustrup or something.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to do all of this, which is why I posted on here. Could you maybe tell me what's wrong with my assignment operator, instead of just saying it's a mess?

Answer (score 0):

How about sending a *trajectory ID* (a number) instead of pointer to the trajectory instance? And having some kind of *trajectory container* mapping trajectory IDs to pointers. Something like:

```
typedef unsigned long long TrajectoryID;
trajectory* TrajectoryContainer::getTrajectory(TrajectoryID id);
```

**EDIT**

> Basically, I want to send them as non-pointers, store them in an array
>   of pointers, and then send them again as non-pointers.

That's really a bad approach. Sending na object as "non-pointer' (that means by value) actually means copying it. And than storing the pointer to the this newly created (copied) instance and than letting this instance to be deleted at the end of the slot scope? That would make the pointer immediately invalid. It's really not the way to go. Consider using that IDs.

**EDIT 2**

Another idea: Derive your trajectory class from the `QObject`. You should be able to send trajectories by pointer than.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. So I would emit a signal containing a number which indicates the location of the specified trajectory in the array of trajectories? If that is what you mean, I'm afraid that wouldn't work, because the receiver doesn't have access to the array. The sender is a child widget and the receiver is the mainwindow.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Maybe you will have to redesign your application a little. Or try what I suggested in the second "edit". Good luck. I have to go now.

Comment: Yeah and by the "trajectory container" I meant a map (std::map, QMap...) rather than an array.

Comment: Okay, I will try your way.

Comment: QObject or no QObject, it *is* possible to send anything by pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to send your custom objects via signals - then try `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE()`. Should be rather easy to implement.

Personal opinion: sending a pointer via signal is ok as long as you keep track of this pointer to prevent leaks(for example, a container that keeps all pointers ever sent; or giving every object a parent immediately after creation). The mentioned idea of using IDs seems like a more elegant way, though. I'd even call it right way, but everyone has his own reasons.